# Show that $i(f) = \int_a^b f \,d\lambda$ and $s(f) = \int_a^b f \,d\lambda$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Full question: For a bounded function $f:[\mathbf{a,b}] \to \mathbb{R}$, set
$\displaystyle i(f) = \inf \left\{\int_a^b g\, d\lambda: g \in C[\mathbf{a,b}], g \geq f\right\}$,   $\displaystyle s(f) = \sup \left\{\int_a^b h \,d \lambda : h \in C [\mathbf{a,b}], h \leq f \right\}$.
Show that $i(f) = \int_a^b f \,d\lambda$ and $s(f) = \int_a^b f \,d\lambda$

I'm pretty sure that I need to use that $d\mu = F' d\lambda$, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: What is the difference between $c$ and $C$?

Comment: Also what is $\mu$ and what is $\lambda$?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $g>f$? Otherwise, $\int_a^bf d\lambda$ is a member the set you're taking the inf of, so you just have to show that it's a lower bound for the set.

Comment: @AOrtiz $\mu$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure

Comment: Look at the following example: let $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is a dyadic rational number, $f(x) = 2$ if $x$ is rational but not dyadic, and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise. What are $i(f)$ and $s(f)$?